# Left and right ruler for the distraction free mode

Tags: sublimetext2

As much as I like the distraction free mode in Sublime, I would like to have some visual guide  to know what the available area is. Is there any way to have both a left and right ruler, or to color the writable area in a lighter tone of gray (I use the monokai them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! Say you have a word wrap at 80 characters like I do, then you only add the following

```
 "rulers": [0,79],
```

to your distraction free mode settings.